# UINavigationBar back button title is hidden when the bar title is too long in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a problem and can't solve it. I'll try to describe the issue, so:

when the title of the `UINavigationBar` is not so long - the situation is like this:

[image]

but if the title of the bar contains more characters - it hides the title of the back button as u can see on the next screenshot:

[image]

Is it a standard `UINavigationBar` behaviour in iOS7? May be there are some ways to solve this? Anyway in `iOS6` the situation is much better - there I can't find any problem like this.

[image]

Comment: imho - it's okay and try to believe to Apple decisions about user experience. And if back button don't have any property about that - try to use custom back button looks same as default.

Comment: `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:yourView]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Simple fix:**

Create one view with label and set that view as a title view to the navigation controller

```
// creating title view 
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)];
    // Adding label with custom frame
    UILabel *labelForTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30)];

    [labelForTitle setCenter:titleView.center];
    [labelForTitle setText:@"sfdfagd ggjhdgfjhadsgfjasgdhfgasdjfgajsdgfjashgdjhfasjdfsadjgfhsadghf"];

    [titleView addSubview:labelForTitle];
    
     // setting title view for the navigation controller.
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleView];
```

output will be like this :

[image]